# Loading a VBA Dictionary which Sums Duplicate Keys

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, vlookup

I am trying to use a dictionary to perform a lookup.  I am getting some incorrect results because of duplicates in the data I am lookup up to.  Below is the "formula version" of my lookup:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Contract]],'Subs Summary'!I:P,8,FALSE),0)
```

The issue is that on the Subs Summary worksheet, the "Contract" (Column I) can have multiple lines with the same contract (and the Vloookup only pulls back the first line it finds the contract on).  I want to perform the lookup via a dictionary and when a duplicate contract occurs, to SUM the values in column P (instead of only retrieving the first instance / line).

Below is my current Code for the dictionary loading and lookup:

```
Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowTwo As Long, shtOrders As Worksheet, shtReport As Worksheet

Set shtOrders = Worksheets("Orders")
Set shtReport = Worksheets("Subs Summary")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'get the lookup dictionary from Report
With shtReport
    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = .Range("I2:I" & lastRow).Value
    x2 = .Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
        dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
    Next i
End With

'map the values
With shtOrders
    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Value       'looks up to this range
    ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)      '<< size the output array
    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
        Else
            y2(i, 1) = "0"
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("CM2:CM" & lastRow).Value = y2     '<< place the output on the sheet
End With
```

This code (I believe) is be performing the Vlookup correctly, but without handling the duplicates at all.  I am trying to code a check if the key (in Column I) exists already in the dictionary, and if so, sum the line's value in Column P to already existing column P values for that contract/key.  There are often times where a key/ contract will have 4 lines in the lookup page (Subs Summary).

Any input is greatly appreciated - I am fairly new to dictionaries and VBA in general, so it could be that my existing code has another issue / inefficiency.  It does run without error and retrieves correct values except for duplicates as far as I can tell.

Cheers!

Comment: The question title is ambiguous: a dictionary **by definition** will not have duplicate keys. But yeah I get what you mean. Don't you want a `SUMIF`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug You are totally right - any suggestion for a more appropriate title?  And yes I think SUMIF (for the situation I described) but I'm not clear as to where the "checking if the contract is duplicate should occur" and what syntax to use

Comment: Look into how `SUMIF` and `SUMIFS` work. You can do this without any code.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am relatively familair with how SUMIFs work on a sheet within a standard formula. This however is just a chunk of a much longer macro which automates an entire process, so I'd like to have the solution in code format.  I'd also like to have the calculation done off sheet (vs. just inserting a SUMIF / Vlookup formula via macro)

Comment: Great! So you won't have any problem using `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf` then!

Comment: @Mat'sMug I'm trying to figure out how to tie my dictionary code, which I am very new to, together with something like `If dict.key.exists then Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf("P2:P" & lastRow,"I2:I" & lastRow)` although I am thinking I need a CountIf in the mix somewhere?  As you mentioned, the key can't exist twice, so I'm chasing my tail a bit on where to perform the SUMIF type operation?  Hopefully that makes sense? Thanks for helping out !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154467/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-rugskid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to adapt my above posted code by adjusting / adding this portion:

```
 If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
    dict.Add x(i, 1), x2(i, 1)
Else
   dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(i, 1))) + CDbl(x2(i, 1))
End If
 Next i
```

SUMIFS did not end up working because there was duplicates on both the "Orders" worksheet as well as the "Subs Summary" worksheet.  Perhaps there is a way to do this using only SUMIFS, but the code (shown below) in it's entirety, works great.

```
Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowTwo As Long, shtOrders As Worksheet, shtReport As Worksheet

Set shtOrders = Worksheets("Orders")
Set shtReport = Worksheets("Subs Summary")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'get the lookup dictionary from Report
With shtReport
    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = .Range("I2:I" & lastRow).Value
    x2 = .Range("P2:P" & lastRow).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)

If Not dict.exists(x(i, 1)) Then
    dict.Add x(i, 1), x2(i, 1)
Else
   dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = CDbl(dict.Item(x(i, 1))) + CDbl(x2(i, 1))
End If
Next i

End With

'map the values
With shtOrders
    lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    y = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Value    'looks up to this range
    ReDim y2(1 To UBound(y, 1), 1 To 1)   '<< size the output array
    For i = 1 To UBound(y, 1)
        If dict.exists(y(i, 1)) Then
            y2(i, 1) = dict(y(i, 1))
        Else
            y2(i, 1) = "0"
        End If
```

Thanks all!
        Next i
        .Range("CM2:CM" & lastRow).Value = y2  '<< place the output on the sheet
    End With